# MariaDB ColumnStore & Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-14.04, mariadb

I see at [mariadb.com](https://mariadb.com/downloads/?fbclid=IwAR0sh7nkA1UUHWf86eeQnmJPo3ozoskmzCh_jBcsM8L3LLw_KsyZyCEGkVU#mariadb_platform-mariadb_columnstore) that MariaDB ColumnStore isn't available to download for Ubuntu 14.04. Is there any way to achieve that?

Comment: @fixer1234 Nope. MariaDB ColumnStore doesn't have an available download for 14.04. Take a look at my printscreen. (https://we.tl/t-aDtuDw9hVt)

Comment: When I clicked yesterday, I saw it, but maybe I somehow ended up looking at the server tab (or they changed it overnight).  :-)  BTW, imgur.com is better for images that you want to share here.  It's what the site uses for its own image storage, and the images are directly available without download.

Comment: If the app is that version-specific, it must have a bunch of dependencies that are version-specific.  They wouldn't invest the time to create those packages if a generic one would work.  You would need to contact them (sales-nam@mariadb.com) and see if the old package is still available for download, or if you can get a generic package that your package manager can use, or source files that you can compile yourself.